# Why isn't Latex labeling my figures with numbers?

Tags: floats

I am trying to label my figures and am using this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=55mm]{limit5.png}
   \caption{Limit cycle corresponding to equation (4)}
\end{figure}
```

This is only labeling my Figures with

```
Figure: Limit cycle corresponding to equation (4)
```

instead of

```
Figure 1: Limit cycle...
```

Help!

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to throw in `\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]` in your preamble to make this work out.